# jquery не хочет работать, после получения html после python через Flask

Tags: python, html, jquery, flask

Структура такая. Пользователь нажимает кнопку сгенерировать таблицу. Это команда передается через `Flask` в `python`. Тот в свою очередь смотрит на кучу серверов собирает инфу + так же собирает `sql` данные. Затем их сравнивает. И на основании всего этого формирует таблицу. Питон файл выплевывает `html` страницу готовую (сохраняя ее как файл). `Flask` возвращает эту страницу через `render_template`.
Визуально все хорошо. Но вот, если пользователь хочет взаимодействовать с таблицей посредством `js`.
Видим ошибку:

```js
main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:1:1
```

Это из шапки сформированной таблицы.

```html
<script defer="" src="static/js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style_for_main.css">
```

Опытным путем, если страницу просто сохранить и корячить ее отдельно `js` работает. Помогите, пожалуйста)))

Comment: А вы уверены, что там нужен `defer` да ещё и в таком странном виде с присваиванием? А если всё-таки нужен, но и все другие скрипты, которые используют `jQuery`, должны идти после подключения `jQuery` и тоже все должны быть `defer`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вы правы убрал defer и стало все корректно работать.

Comment: Оформите как ответ. Я добавлю решение.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script defer="" src="static/js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        ^^^^^
<script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
```

Проблема в том, что в строке подключения библиотеки `jQuery` у вас стоит атрибут `defer`. А в тех строках, где `jQuery` используется, этот атрибут не стоит.
В результате попытка **использования** библиотеки `jQuery` происходит **раньше её подключения**, отсюда и такая ошибка.

Само по себе использование атрибута `defer` - это не проблема и в некоторых гайдах это даже рекомендуется, чтобы страница быстрее грузилась и показывалась, а скрипты уже потом отрабатывали. Но в случае загрузки библиотеки `jQuery` с атрибутом `defer` таким же атрибутом `defer` должны быть снабжены все вызовы `jQuery` на странице и, кроме того, подключение библиотеки должно идти раньше её использования. Тогда подключение и использование `jQuery` будет произведено правильным образом.

P.S. И вообще тут странное что-то у вас, атрибуту `defer` не нужно ничего присваивать, он используется сам по себе.